# HTTP 500 Error when trying to post with Java

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to POST to a server and am getting HTTP 500 errors when getting the response. I've checked to make sure my params are correctly formatted. If anyone could tell me why my code isn't working I would greatly appreciate it!

```
String params = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
postConnection.setDoOutput(true);
postConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
OutputStream output = postConnection.getOutputStream();
output.write(params.getBytes("UTF-8"));
output.flush();
output.close();
InputStream postResponse = postConnection.getInputStream(); //error happens here
int inputByte = postResponse.read();
while (inputByte != -1){
    postResponseRawJSON += (char)inputByte;
    inputByte = postResponse.read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't urlencode your query string.

UPDATE

In a POST message, the body of the request is of the form:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2...
```

if you encode the whole query line, the '='s and '&'s will be escaped and the server will not be able to retrieve the parameters.

Some of your parameter values may need to be encoded; but you must encode them separately:

```
String params = "param1=" + URLEncoder.encode(value1, "UTF-8")
        + "&param2=" + URLEncoder.encode(value2, "UTF-8")
        ...
```